# lvmcache: failed to connect to lvmetad on Debian Stretch during boot

Tags: boot, cache, debian-stretch, lvm2

I have a freshly set up HP Microserver with Debian Stretch. I set up a RAID5 with LVM on top and built an lvmcache. `home` is a symlink pointing to a directory on that LVM. Its mounted via `/etc/fstab` (after `/`, of course). Set up the lvmcache like [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmcache.7.html).I already set this up twice. No effort.

I can boot when removing the lvmcache from data partition. When I enable the cache on a running system, the cache is used and works. So, it's a boot problem.

When the error appears, `lvscan` shows the data partition is inactive. It says waiting to connect to lvmetad and it's waiting 1:30mins for a strange device name (somethiong like /dev/mapper/**x2d**...). I dont have this device name on my machine.

**Workaround** (disabling the cache during boot):

```
lvconvert --splitcache server-vg/data
lvchange -ay server-vg/data
lvscan                            # check if its active again.
```

This is the only one thing I changed and then its booting again. But I'd really like to use this cache.

```
  # lvs -a
  LV                 VG        Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  cache-data         server-vg Cwi---C--- 20,00g                                                    
  [cache-data_cdata] server-vg Cwi------- 20,00g                                                    
  [cache-data_cmeta] server-vg ewi------- 24,00m                                                    
  data               server-vg -wi-ao----  1,82t                                                    
  [lvol0_pmspare]    server-vg ewi------- 24,00m                                                    
  root               server-vg -wi-ao---- 27,94g                                                    
  swap_1             server-vg -wi-ao----  3,96g
```

Here, you can see the cache policy mq is set. At beginning this was set to smq, The change did not help. [from here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736532/lvmcache-failed-to-boot-device-mapper-cache-policy-unknown-policy-type)

```
# lvs -o+cache_policy,cache_settings server-vg/cache-data
  LV         VG        Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert CachePolicy CacheSettings
  cache-data server-vg Cwi---C--- 20,00g                                                     mq
```

Please let me know if you need further info. Don't want to post tons of output here while I don't know if its helpful.

I already googled a lot but did not find any solutions for this problem related to lvmcache. But I also did not find any posts saying that Debian is not able to use lvmcache...

This [cache_check solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/1423796) for a similar problem also didn't fix anything for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met the problem same with you.

I have 3 lvs(collection, study, anonymous) in a vg(nasvg) and use a ssd for study-lv with lvmcache. Nothing wrong happened when I installing it, but when I reboot, I got the same output with you. After I commented the mount of study-lv in `/etc/fstab`, it boots successfully. Also, `lvscan`shows the study-lv `inactive`, and once I try to active it, I got that
 `/usr/sbin/cache_check execvp failed no such file or directory`

I got help from here https://bugs.launchpad.net/devstack/+bug/1615134. Seem that the lack of package "thin-provisioning-tools" make my lvmcache down.

Then, with `sudo apt-get install thin-provisioning-tools`, and `sudo vgchange -a y nasvg`, everything was ok and I can boot successfully now with lvmcache.

Here is my evironment:

ubuntu 18.04(amd64)

LVM version: 2.02.176(2) (2017-11-03)

Comment: You are my hero!! Another pproblem  with my server was the USB backup disk which was mounted in `/etc/fstab` automatically. Added the options `noauto,user,defaults` here. That caused the timeout error.